# Facebook connect

Tags: facebook

I have an asp.net site and I use it to log in to Facebook calling
http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=API_KEY&connect_display=popup&v=1.0&next=http://localhost/site/login.aspx&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html&fbconnect=true&return_session=true&skipcookie=true
It logs in very well, returns to my site, and I see the session parameter in the URL, but I can't catch any postback or something.
Could you help me, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us at least some code. It is really unclear

Comment: It's a link that sends there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

- Make sure that http://localhost/site (or whatever the url for the root of your app is) is set in your application's connect settings
- If you're using the Visual Studio development studio development web server (Cassini), your app's url will include a port (for example, http://localhost:34256/site). This url (including the port) will need to be specified in your connect url in your application's settings on Facebook.